# Not by somebody VS by not somebody

Tags: prepositions, word-order

Which variant is correct?

1. She is being thought about by not him.
2. She is being thought about not by him.

Answer (score 1):

Sentence 1 is not correct, as I understand it.

Sentence 2 is more correct IF you continue it:

> 2) She is being thought about **not** by him, **but** by [her mother].

In this way, you use the construct: "not (by) ... but (by)...". If you do NOT continue the sentence, it sounds incomplete.

Comment: So, I can say "it was done not by me" but "it was done by not me" would be incorrect, right?

Comment: @MichaelAzarenko: yes, you can say however you want, but it does not mean it is correct. I explained why your examples provided in the question are incorrect. So, according to my explanation, the sentences in your comment are incorrect (assuming that the explanation is correct).

Comment: self-criticism: I did a great job overusing "correct" and "incorrect"

Comment: @MichaelAzarenko Note that the most common way of phrasing your sentence is to move *not* to the front: *She is* ***not*** *being thought about by him*. But that may assume a subtly different meaning than what you want—and it means something different than what was provided in this answer (which is also a correct rephrasing).

Comment: Yes, if we say "She is not thought about by him" it will mean there is no thinking activity about her from him, but I wanted to show there was some activity but not from him.
So, "by not him" can't exist in any case? Only "not by him", right? Like, "by somebody" construction is unseparable? Just reasking for the 100% assurance.

Comment: @MichaelAzarenko People would say: He doesn't think about her. "by not  him" is wrong. Someone thinks about her but not him. Your passives don't  work.

Answer (score 0):

> ”She is being thought about **not** *by him* (*but by someone else*)”

Here, **”by him”** is a *prepositional phrase*. We cannot place *’not’* between the preposition *’by’* & its object *’him’*. Therefore, *”by not him”* is incorrect. The *’not’* must be placed before the prepositional phase in this case.